# Database in docker container won't talk to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker-compose

Btw if you don't know Ruby on Rails I don't think you'll be able to answer this. I'm on linux and running the db and services in docker containers using a compose file.

db says: database system is ready to accept connections and that it's listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432", while `bundle exec rails db:setup` says connection to server on socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

I have already tried editing the database.yml file so that they say the exactly the same thing. i.e. so that both say "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432".

Am I correct in thinking that it's probably because rails is looking on my local system rather than the container? How do I change this? PostgreSQL in docker-compose.yml ports are mapped to "5432:5432".

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: could you share your docker-compose.yml and database.yml (without any secrets/passwords of course) ?  
you have an excellent tutorial [here](https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/) if it is of any help

Comment: anyway you should try to connect to the TCP port `db:5432` instead of a unix socket